# Unit test for a vector

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Please,I was searching it here, but couldn't do it correctly.

So I have a function which returns to me the `vector` of sortig numbers. Then I tried to create a using test for this very vector.

Here is what I have right now:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "Finder.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace FinderUnitTest
{       

    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {
    public:


        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            Finder f;
            std::vector<int> v1 = f.find_words();
             //find_words(); is working okay without tests

            for (int i=0;i<1;i++)
                Assert::AreEqual(57,v1[i]);
        }

    };
}
```

It really doesn't matter, how many time `for` goes. I'd like to get the unit test without mistake, I have one right now, it is:

> Message: Invalid parameter detected in function std::vector >::operator [], c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\vector line 1795. Expression: **"vector subscript out of range"**

How I get that when I build my two projects, my fuction, which returns the vector of sorting numbers,doesn't have any data because when I run the test,there is empty. Am I right?

I just want to compare two first numbers of my vector with `57`.

Comment: `for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 2 && i < v1.size(); i++)`

Comment: @razzorflame  OMG, thank youm! Put this like an answer,please. Explain, if you can, why I should put: `&& i < v1.size()`

Comment: I don't think this is complete answer. You have completely other problem. I only told you how to go through indices 0 and 1 and ensure to stop before acquiring invalid element. Your problem is that `find_words` returns empty vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting find_words to return a vector like [57, 57, ...] then this test should fail. However, it should not error, but rather it should Assert. You want to fix your checks so they detect the problem as an assert violation.

```
Finder f;
std::vector<int> v1 = f.find_words();

Assert::IsTrue(v1.size() >= 2); // there are at least two entries
Assert::AreEqual(57,v1[0]); // the first is 57
Assert::AreEqual(57,v1[1]); // the second is 57
```

I don't see where you gave finder anything to search, but if you say it should find 57's, you're the boss. Just be sure to check that. Once the unittest gives this assert, the unittest has done its job, and you can go back and see if you gave Finder the right inputs, or if there is a bug inside Finder.

X21's comment was good programming practice about how to detect and avoid the crash. It fixes the crash by not checking the values at all, since to do so would be an error. It was not directed at writing a unit test. The unit test must detect and assert when the output is not what you expect. Crashing would be better than not checking at all, inside a test.

Comment: Okay, I got you. But what if I want to compare to vectros `Assert::AreEqual(v2[i],v1[0]);` . Is it possible?

Comment: Well, obviously yes, if those are supposed to be equal. But first you would Assert::IsTrue(v2.size() > i); Assert::IsTrue(v1.size() > 0); Tests don't trust the thing being tested.